# Copy class + package-context between projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, package, copy-paste

For a number of uninteresting reasons: we need to copy many classes from one project to another (while preserving the package-structure of said classes).

In other words, given:

```
origin/src/com/foo/bar/A
origin/src/com/baz/qux/B

dest/ <empty>
```

We want to copy A and B such that we end up with:

```
dest/src/com/foo/bar/A
dest/src/com/baz/qux/B
```

Presently, we are forced to manually create the packages in `dest` and then `Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V` the individual .java files between projects.  What we would like to do is to have Eclipse automatically copy the files over while automatically creating the packages (hence, preserving the package structure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presently, there is no clean pre-built solution for this.  The answer is to write a script using any language of your choosing.

This is exactly what I did: using Python.

Comment: But why isn't it better to use @maestr0 solution? Isn't it clean?

Answer (score 5):

You can just copy the files between your project folders using a shell script. Eclipse will pick up the copied java files including the package structure.

If you select all the files in the source project in Navigator Window panel (not Package Explorer) you should be able to CTRL+C/V the whole file structure preserving packages to a new project.

Answer (score 0):

A workaroud is possible.

**Select the package** -> **Right Click** -> **Export** -> Select **Archive File** -> **Finish**.

Now **Select Destination package** -> **Right Click** -> **Import** -> Select **Archive File** -> **Finish**.

The imported packages/files are copied into a new package with name *Source_project_name.<source_package_structure>*.

Now Press `F2` or right-click and **Rename**. Change the package name and select **Rename subpackages** option. Click **OK**.